How to preserve the scope for a background operation
we use Serilog scoped logging via ILogger.BeginScope:
logger.BeginScope("Foo");
logger.BeginScope("Bar");

--> This creates two nested scopes [Foo] and [Bar].

Sending notification is an example which can take time and should not make the user waiting for it.
Our problem is that in such background operation (i.e. IHostedService) the log scope is lost:
 internal class NotificationWorker : IHostedService
 {
  ...
  Task QueueWorkAsync (object someContext) {
    ...
    logger.LogInformation ("Queueing");
  }

  Task DoWorkAsync (CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
  {
    ...
    logger.LogInformation ("Hello World");
  }


We queue work via QueueWorkAsync. At this point in time, the log scope is populated correctly:
[INF]: [Foo],[Bar] Queueing
When DoWorkAsync is called, the scope is empty:
[INF]: Hello World

How can we forward/ preserve the scope for a worker?
I tried

to pass the log instance into the worker, which had positive effect.
clone the LogContext and push it in the task, i.e.

Task QueueWorkAsync (object someContext) 
{
    ...
    logger.LogInformation ("Queueing");
    var workContext = new TaskContext (  LogContext = LogContext.Clone(); }
}

Task DoWorkAsync (TaskContext taskContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
{
    ...
    LogContext.Push(taskContext.LogContext);
    logger.LogInformation ("Hello World");  // no scope available
}

Is this actually possible?
